# ¿Cómo comparo datos en una matriz?

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo haría un código en Python que me permita comparar datos de esta matriz segun la letra (columna) que el usuario elija?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Es decir si el usuario quiere comparar los rasgos de las letras p,k y h, el código debería arrojar que tienen en común los siguientes rasgos y valores:
sonoro (-)
nasal (-)
redondo (-)
distribuido (-)
lateral (-)
bajo (-)

Recordando que el usuario puede escoger las letras o sonidos que quiera comparar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo voy hacer mención del algoritmo para la comparación de datos de la sub matriz que corresponde a la seleccion de las letras señaladas en la pregunta. Para ello puedes hacer uso de un diccionario para asignar el código correspondiente al rasgo común.

La matrix general se transpone para facilitar la selección de la letra y la sub matriz de letras se vuelve a transponer para facilitar la selección de los rasgos comunes. Los rasgos comunes se evaluan en una lista por comprensión de una sola línea (en el código siguiente se presenta en dos por razones de legilibilidad) y finalmente se imprimen por consola.

El código completo se señala a continuación:

```
import numpy as np

letters = {'p':0, 't':1, 'tj':2, 'c':3, 'k':4, 'kw':5, 'q':6, 'G':7, 'h':8}

features = {0:'sonoro', 1:'sonorante', 2:'obstruyente', 3:'consonantal', 4:'plosiva',
            5:'continuante', 6:'nasal', 7:'labial', 8:'redondo', 9:'coronal', 
            10:'estridente', 11:'anterior', 12:'distribuido', 13:'lateral', 14:'dorsal', 
            15:'alto', 16:'posterior', 17:'bajo', 18:'Silabico', 19:'Retraido'}


matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], #sonoro
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #sonorante
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], #obstruyente
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], #consonantal
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], #plosiva
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], #continuante
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #nasal
          [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], #labial
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], #redondo
          [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #coronal
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #estridente
          [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #anterior
          [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #distribuido
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #lateral
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], #dorsal
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], #alto
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], #posterior
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #bajo
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #Silabico
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]] #Retraido

t_matrix = np.transpose(matrix)

selected_matrix = [ t_matrix[0],  #p
                    t_matrix[4],  #k
                    t_matrix[8] ] #h

t_selected_matrix = np.transpose(selected_matrix)

common_features = [ features[i] for i, list in enumerate(t_selected_matrix)
                      if all(x == list[0] for x in list) ]

for feature in common_features:
    print feature
```

Después de la ejecución se obtiene lo siguiente:

```
sonoro
sonorante
nasal
redondo
coronal
estridente
distribuido
lateral
bajo
Silabico
```

que corresponde a lo esperado.

**Nota de Edición:**

Para incorporar simultáneamente el value '(-)' o '(+)' sólo basta definir un diccionario adicional de values como en el código siguiente:

```
import numpy as np

letters = {'p':0, 't':1, 'tj':2, 'c':3, 'k':4, 'kw':5, 'q':6, 'G':7, 'h':8}

features = {0:'sonoro', 1:'sonorante', 2:'obstruyente', 3:'consonantal', 4:'plosiva',
            5:'continuante', 6:'nasal', 7:'labial', 8:'redondo', 9:'coronal', 
            10:'estridente', 11:'anterior', 12:'distribuido', 13:'lateral', 14:'dorsal', 
            15:'alto', 16:'posterior', 17:'bajo', 18:'Silabico', 19:'Retraido'}

values = {0:'(-)', 1:'(+)'}

matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], #sonoro
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #sonorante
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], #obstruyente
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], #consonantal
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], #plosiva
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], #continuante
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #nasal
          [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], #labial
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], #redondo
          [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #coronal
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #estridente
          [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #anterior
          [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #distribuido
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #lateral
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], #dorsal
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], #alto
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], #posterior
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #bajo
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #Silabico
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]] #Retraido

t_matrix = np.transpose(matrix)

selected_matrix = [ t_matrix[0],  #p
                    t_matrix[4],  #k
                    t_matrix[8] ] #h

t_selected_matrix = np.transpose(selected_matrix)

common_features = [ [features[i],list[0]] for i, list in enumerate(t_selected_matrix)
                    if all(x == list[0] for x in list) ]

for feature in common_features:
    print feature[0], values[feature[1]]
```

Comment: Wooow Muchísimas gracias por tomarte la molestia de presentar una respuetsa también explicada. Ignoraba la existencia de ese NumPy. De verdad muchas gracias..Solo que tambien necesityo imprimir el valor (- o +) . Es decir si bien tienen el rasgo sonoro en comun, debo imprimir realmte sonoro (-) porque en ese rasgo el valor es menos asi tambien los otros rasgos comunes.

Comment: Ya está incorporada esa funcionalidad en la **Nota de Edición**.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @xunilk. Eso lo califico como una **Excelentee** Ayuda

Comment: Disculpa @xunik para que seria la lista letters?

Comment: Para saber que **t_matrix[0]** corresponde a la "p", **t_matrix[4]**  a la "k" y así sucesivamente. Cuando contesté esta pregunta tenía el tag PyQt5. Por tanto, cuando hagas click en el **QPushButton** que corresponde a la "p" y conecte al slot correspondiente, el diccionario "letters" permitirá seleccionar  **t_matrix[0]** y no otra para conformar la  **selected_matrix** que incluye todas las letras.